# is there another way except stringstream, to concatenate a string consist of more than type of variables?

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

When we need to concatenate a string with data from more than one variable type, we usually do the following:

```
int year = 2013;
float amount = 385.5;

stringstream concat;
string strng;
concat << "I am in the year " << year << " and I don't have in my pocket but the amount " << amount;
strng = concat.str();

cout << strng << endl;
```

As we see in that code, we concatenate many types of data: `year` is *int* type, `amount` is a *float* and the string `I am in the year` is a *string* type. In other programming languages you can do the same by using the `+` operator.

So, going back to the question:
Is there another way **except** `stringstream`, to concatenate a string (`char` or `string` type) while inputting data from more than one type of variable in `C` and `C++` languages? I'd like to be able to do it in both languages.

Comment: You can do something like `std::string str = "Hello " + std::to_string("World!");` but quite honestly the `std::stringstream` way is probably better.

Comment: `sprintf` for C and the [Boost format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) for C++.

Comment: snprintf is in vogue now, right?

Comment: If you're thinking of using `sprintf()`, always use `snprintf()` instead - one less chance of a buffer overrun. Whenever you use unbounded string functions (`sprintf()`, `strcpy()`, etc) you should *always* ask yourself whether there's a good reason you're not using the bounded version instead. It's just good practice.

Comment: How do you intend to concatenate to a `std::string` in C? Do you really need to do this in both languages? If you, you can move down to the C form of the concatenation, but that will be more painful than needed if your target is C++. C and C++ are **different** languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using stringstream is certainly very convenient, but not the only way.  One way is to use [sprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) and another is to convert all value types to strings via methods like [itoa()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) or ftoa() and use the standard string concatination method [strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) to combine multiple strings together.

Comment: Did you mean sprintf/snprintf?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vsnprintf()` to implement a kind of wrapper to print into a string that is dynamically expanded as needed. On Linux, a C solution exists in the form of `asprintf()`, and it returns memory that has to be released with `free()`:

```
char *concat;
asprintf(&concat, "I am in the year %d and I don't have in my pocket but the amount %f",
         year, amount);
std::string strng(concat);
free(concat);
```

In C++, you can implement something a little more use friendly, since RAII can take care of memory management issues for you:

```
int string_printf (std::string &str, const char *fmt, ...) {
    char buf[512];
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int r = vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (r < sizeof(buf)) {
        if (r > 0) str.insert(0, buf);
        return r;
    }
    std::vector<char> bufv(r+1);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    r = vsnprintf(&bufv[0], bufv.size(), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (r > 0) str.insert(0, &bufv[0]);
    return r;
}


std::string strng;
string_printf(strng,
              "I am in the year %d and I don't have in my pocket but the amount %f",
              year, amount);
```